# How to write Simple Security in WSO2 ESB Using Security Policy's?

Tags: apache-axis, ws-security, wso2, wso2-esb

I wish to provide security to my Proxy using simple Username and password but my client has fixed request which is entirely different with what wso2esb policies provide Wso2 esb Support for Username Token authentication .I m also want to check just Username&Password.But the pain is my request is not meet to wso2 esb Username Token format.
Difference between messages what wso2 expecting ..
My Client Message is

```
<soapenv:Header>
          <pr:authentication soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:pr="http://webservices.eeeee.com/ProxyService">
             <pr:user>mw_ssp</pr:user>
             <pr:password>MW_ssp003</pr:password>
          </pr:authentication>
       </soapenv:Header>
```

Actual message which wso2 esb expecting is

```
<soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-4">
            <wsu:Created>2014-06-02T07:15:21Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2014-06-02T08:38:41Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-3">
            <wsse:Username>admin</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">admin</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">byWKVY4stEATvTqaoNMswQ==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2014-06-02T07:15:21.304Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse: >
   </soapenv:Header>
```

I just want change Header as per the Username Token works.How  would i achieve this
Any help much appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: IS there any information  about above question.